# how to control the execution of rescue module in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook like this below ,i want to control execution of rescue when the block goes wrong。
I add `when: is_debug is defined` after rescue ，but when i run `ansible-playbook dashboard.yml`  ,not give the is_debug value, the rescue is still excute when block has error .

i want know how to control the execution of rescue module in ansible ?

```
[root@ansiable-test update]# cat dashboard.yml
---
- hosts: controller
  vars_files:
        - "vars/vars.yml"
  tasks:
    - name: update horizon
    - block:
        - include: "roles/dashboard/tasks/update-horizon.yml"
      rescue:
      when: is_debug is defined
        - debug: msg='An error occurred during the upgrade,roll back to the old version'
        - include: "roles/dashboard/tasks/rollback.yml"
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no `rescue` "module". It's part of the `block` syntax, and you cannot apply `when` to just the `rescue` portion.  You can apply the `when` condition to the task (or tasks) inside your `rescue` stanza:

```
- hosts: controller
  vars_files:
        - "vars/vars.yml"
  tasks:
    - name: update horizon
    - block:
        - include: "roles/dashboard/tasks/update-horizon.yml"
      rescue:
        - debug: msg='An error occurred during the upgrade,roll back to the old version'
          when: is_debug is defined

        - include: "roles/dashboard/tasks/rollback.yml"
          when: is_debug is defined
```